# Using nose plugin to pass a boolean to my package

Tags: python-2.7, nosetests

Can a variable be moved from the cmd to my module when using nose tests?

Scenario: I am running tests with selenium that need to run against both production and sandbox versions of the website (www.sandbox.myurl.com and www.myurl.com)

I wrote a custom nose plugin that lets me set which environment to run against

**EDITED CODE**

```
env = None

class EnvironmentSelector(Plugin):
"""Selects if test will be run against production or sandbox environments.
"""

def __init__(self):
    Plugin.__init__(self)
    self.environment = "spam"  ## runs against sandbox by default

def options(self, parser, env):
    """Register command line options"""
    parser.add_option("--set-env",
                      action="store",
                      dest="setEnv",
                      metavar="ENVIRON",
                      help="Run tests against production or sandbox"
                      "If no --set-env specified, runs against sandbox by default")

def configure(self, options, config):
    """Configure the system, based on selected options."""

    #set variable to that which was passed in cmd
    self.environment = options.setEnv
    self.enabled = True

    global env
    print "This is env before: " + str(env)
    env = self.passEnv()
    print "This is env after: " str(env)
    return env

def passEnv(self):
    run_production = False

    if self.environment.lower() == "sandbox":
        print ("Environment set to sandbox")
        return run_production

    elif self.environment.lower() == "prod":
        print ("Environmnet set to prod")
        run_production = True
        return run_production

    else:
        print ("NO environment was set, running sandbox by default")
        return run_production
```

In my package, I have a `@setup` function that passes the appropriate URL to the webdriver before running the test suite.

At the top of the module with my `setup()` in it, I have

```
from setEnvironment import env
```

I included a print statement with the value of `env` in the setup function

Whiles `env` gets set in setEnvironment.py as `True`, it gets imported as `None`, which was env's original assignment.

How do I get the variable to successfully import into `@setup`??

**SETUP.PY**

Here's what I run everytime I make an adjustment to the setEnvironment script.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Custom nose plugins',
    version='0.6.0',
    description = 'setup Prod v. Sandbox environment',
    py_modules = ['setEnvironment'],
    entry_points = {
        'nose.plugins': [
            'setEnvironment = setEnvironment:EnvironmentSelector'
            ]
        }
    )
```

Comment: A stack trace of the error when you import your plugin directly would be helpful.

Comment: I added env as a global variable, so I no longer get the error, but I still can't get the variable import into setup with the correct value.  See edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the way you are doing it the value of the variable is assigned on import.
Try something like this:

```
#at the top of the setup() module
import setEnvironment
...

#in setup() directly
print "env =", setEnvironment.env
```

You also have some minor typos in your code. The following should work (setEnvironment.py):

```
from nose.plugins.base import Plugin

env = None

class EnvironmentSelector(Plugin):
    """Selects if test will be run against production or sandbox environments.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        Plugin.__init__(self)
        self.environment = "spam"  ## runs against sandbox by default

    def options(self, parser, env):
        """Register command line options"""
        parser.add_option("--set-env",
                          action="store",
                          dest="setEnv",
                          metavar="ENVIRON",
                          help="Run tests against production or sandbox"
                          "If no --set-env specified, runs against sandbox by default")

    def configure(self, options, config):
        """Configure the system, based on selected options."""

        #set variable to that which was passed in cmd
        self.environment = options.setEnv
        self.enabled = self.environment

        if self.enabled:
            global env
            print "This is env before: " + str(env)
            env = self.passEnv()
            print "This is env after: " + str(env)
            return env

    def passEnv(self):
        run_production = False

        if self.environment.lower() == "sandbox":
            print ("Environment set to sandbox")
            return run_production

        elif self.environment.lower() == "prod":
            print ("Environmnet set to prod")
            run_production = True
            return run_production

        else:
            print ("NO environment was set, running sandbox by default")
            return run_production
```

And here is my testing code (pg_test.py), to run with straight python:

```
import logging
import sys

import nose

from nose.tools import with_setup

import setEnvironment

def custom_setup():
    #in setup() directly
    print "env =", setEnvironment.env


@with_setup(custom_setup)
def test_pg():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    module_name = sys.modules[__name__].__file__

    logging.debug("running nose for package: %s", module_name)
    result = nose.run(argv=[sys.argv[0],
                            module_name,
                            '-s',
                            '--nologcapture',
                            '--set-env=prod'
                            ],
                      addplugins=[setEnvironment.EnvironmentSelector()],)
    logging.info("all tests ok: %s", result)
```

And when I ran it, I got:

```
$ python pg_test.py
This is env before: None
Environmnet set to prod
This is env after: True
env = True
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work.  In `setEnvironment` I changed the global variable to `env = None`.  In set.Environment.config() I added print statements to show that the global variable is getting updated in my nose plugin.  But in my setup() even though I include `from setEnvironment import env` `env` is still coming through as None, which was `env`'s original assignment

Comment: That is why you should do what I suggested, do not use `from setEnv..` and use `import setEnvironment` and late variable access with `setEnvironment.env` when you actually need it.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand python enough to see why that type of import would make a difference, but even trying your suggestion to the letter, the variable does not get passed correctly.

Comment: Is it `None`, `True` or `False`?

Comment: The value that is getting passed is `None`

Comment: Perhaps it is something with my setup.py?  I've added the code in my original post

Comment: I gave you a fully working code, that passes all of the criteria of the question. Give it a try and see for yourself that it works. If it does not, please let me know.

Comment: Copying and pasting both sets of code above, it still does not work.  Running the test code, I get `This is env before: None` `Environment set to prod` `This is env after: True` `env=None`  Everything I've read says that your code should work!  Feeling defeated at this point...

Comment: Never give up! There is a nice trick that you can use to debug this type of issue, it is called sys.settrace http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201311/adhoc_data_breakpoints.html You can turn trace right after "This is env after: True" and see who clears it.