# Passing args to nose.runmodule()

Tags: python, argparse, nose

I switched from unittest to nose to be able to specify concurrent processing and xunit report generation. My python file contains several test functions and a nontest function that the test functions call during testing. I know that tests should be automated to the point that no arguments need to be passed in, when testing. However, I want to the user be able to change the defaults, if he so wishes. So, I use argparse to parse the arguments. Following is a sample of the test script. I haven't included several other test functions present in the original file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from nose.tools import nottest
from nose.tools import assert_equals
import nose
import unittest
import argparse
import sys

@nottest
def open_browser():
    browser = eval('webdriver.%s()'%browserType)
    return browser

def test_google_title():
    browser = open_browser()
    browser.get("http://www.google.com")
    assert_equals("Google", browser.title)
    browser.quit()

def test_yahoo_title():
    browser = open_browser()
    browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
    assert_equals("Yahoo", browser.title)
    browser.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--browser", choices=['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],default='PhantomJS')
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    browserType = args.browser

    try:
        sys.argv.remove('--browser')
        sys.argv.remove(args.browser)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    nose.runmodule()
```

I read args.browser into browserType, which is later used by open_browser(). When I run,

```
python test.py --browser 'Chrome' -v --with-xunit
```

**It runs fine**.

However, when I run,

```
python test.py --browser 'Chrome' -v --with-xunit --processes 2 --process-timeout 10
```

**It fails with the error**,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/indrajeet/.virtualenv/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/indrajeet/scripts/test.py", line 15, in test_google_title
    browser = open_browser()
  File "/Users/indrajeet/scripts/test.py", line 11, in open_browser
    browser = eval('webdriver.%s()'%browserType)
NameError: global name 'browserType' is not defined
```

I need the flexibility to pass in additional options to nose such as --processes, --process-timeout without having to specify them in parser.

Any ideas? Thanks for reading...

Comment: I think you need to give us the error stack. What happens if you replace the `argparse` call with a simple `environment = 'a'` statement?

Comment: @Indrajeet Do I miss some import? Please, provide complete example. I miss `argparse`, @nontest shall be probably `@nottest` and shall be imported form `nose.tools`

Comment: @hpaulj I have updated my question with the error stack. Replacing argparse with statically assigning the browser changes nothing. Also, I just realized that it is only when I ask nose to run tests concurrently that it throws up the error.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky I have updated my question with an updated example.

Comment: So `nose` or `unittest` is isolating the tested functions from the `__main__` namespace.

Comment: @hpaulj The code provided runs well if there is no concurrency. I am effectively able to print out value of `browserType` from `openBrowser` function.

Comment: @Indrajeet I can confirm, that your code now runs and behaves as you describe. This means, it runs in running in single process, and fails if in multiple ones. I would propose you file it as a bug at `nose` https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second instance of the nose (you are asking nose to run with two cores with `--processes 2`) does not evaluate `__main__` and thus your browser variable never gets set. You can reproduce this error by running `nosetests test.py`.

If you intend on using multiprocessing plugin, you may have to invest some time and get proper  plugin in place that will parse your arguments properly, similar to this question: [Using nose plugin to pass a boolean to my package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944330/using-nose-plugin-to-pass-a-boolean-to-my-package)