# Running nosetests and python standalone scripts

Tags: python, parsing, testing, config, nose

I have a python script which looks like this:

```
class TestMe(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
```

This config file is passed from main which looks like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    config = c.parse_config()
    test = TestMe(config)
```

The python script is run using "python script.py -c1 config.py" (I change '-c' to '-c1' since nosetests also use the '-c' option)

I want to run the same "script.py" using nosetests but how do I pass the config file to nose tests. I want to use something that's compatible for both.

With the above code, nosetest does not like that I pass "config" to **init**() in "class TestMe". How can I pass it otherwise so the same script can be run with both nosetests and python script (standalone with '-c1' option).

Comment: Paulo Bu - not necessarily. I dont use TestBase but my tests work.

Comment: <code> from testconfig import config as c

class TestMe(object):
    def test_a(self):
        assert 'c' == 'c'
        print "I am here"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = c.parse_config()
    test = TestMe(config) <code>

Comment: Sorry, I misread the documentation. Still, is not that clear to me what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you have unit tests for the TestMe class written (it's not clear as you haven't shown/mentioned them). Are you able to run the unittests at all (e.g. without nose?). If so, how do you run them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nose-testconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig/) for this, with some minor modifications.

Comment: HI Oleksiy: I added some more comments/code to my first question. I am not sure what kind of changes are required..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944330/using-nose-plugin-to-pass-a-boolean-to-my-package